# How to optimize multiple filter?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have big search panel with filters
[image: search panel]
In the computed section I use the next code

```
computed: {
    filteredItems() {
      if (this.activeFilter && this.activeFilter != 'all') {
        return this.items[this.activeFilter]
          .filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
          .filter(item => item.itemLevel >= this.minLvl && item.itemLevel <= this.maxLvl);
      } else {
        let all = [];
        let i;
        if (this.items) {
          for (i = 0; i < this.filters.length; i++) {
            Array.prototype.push.apply(all, this.items[this.filters[i].value]);
          }
        }
        return all
          .filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
          .filter(item => {
            if (this.minLvl !== '' && this.maxLvl !== '') {
              if (item.itemLevel >= this.minLvl && item.itemLevel <= this.maxLvl) return true;
            } else if (this.minLvl == '' && this.maxLvl !== '') {
              if (item.itemLevel <= this.maxLvl) return true;
            } else if (this.minLvl !== '' && this.maxLvl == '') {
              if (item.itemLevel >= this.minLvl) return true;
            } else {
              return true;
            }
          });
      }
    },
  }
```

Here is I use one filter for min and max level. And when I will add more filter my code will be too big. Multiple filters can be active l at the same time.
How can I optimize my code?

Comment: This is more of a question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You need a bit more context to make this on-topic on CR